# Is a permit required to replace air ducts?

Tags: hvac, ducts

I’m doing a major renovation of my townhome. I plan to apply for permits for the electrical, plumbing, support beams, etc.

Now that it’s gutted, and just studs, etc. can I swap out my old air ducts or do I need a permit? The house is from 1993 and smells terrible from a smoking tenant. It looks like I should be able to just replace them.

The home is in Fairfax County, by the way.

Thanks!

Comment: Your local building department will be the best ones to ask.  Might need a permit in your town, but not in the next town over.

Comment: Looks like FFX requires HVAC permits.  If you replace ducts, you probably need to bring them up to current code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions of local code are off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you need a permit, but the calculations for airflow and sufficient duct work are required, if your ductwork provides too much back-pressure on the coils, or not enough airflow from the intakes, you will see AC cooling problems as the lack of airflow over the coil will permit the humidity in the air to freeze onto the coil.

Keep in mind that many homes are not built with sufficient ductwork or intake, even when constructed new.  For example, my decade long AC problem was fixed only after running a new duct and return, and enlarging the single return the builders installed.  So, simply replacing ducts with similar is not always the correct path.

Hard ducts are preferred (and more expensive) as they withstand cleaning more easily.  If you are considering automated or motor controlled dampeners (a dampener should be installed for every duct outlet), keep in mind that you need to provide sufficient air movement with the dampeners closed, which generally means limiting the number of dampeners that can be closed at one time while ensuring that the remaining lines have sufficient air handling to keep coil freezing from occurring.

Comment: Also, it is a bad idea to put a "slightly" large AC unit on a refurbishment, unless the original unit was underpowered.  Cooling a home too quickly causes condensation on the back side of the drywall, which cases all sorts of extra problems one doesn't see until its too late.

Comment: The more important thing for ducting is ensuring you have sufficient make up air such that you never have depressurization occurring and pulling combustion products into the house and killing you.

Comment: Thank you everyone!